# Very messed up display with Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display, budgie

Today afternoon my Ubuntu machine very randomly decided that it would be good to crash and completely mess up the display for no apparent reason. As of now Ubuntu is now throwing me really dirty looks like:

[image: forgive me but my hands trend to shake a bit when I am nervous]

So ignoring the Samsung and the rest if the junk on the table and concentrating on the really dirty looks my computer's giving me is there anything I can do recover my PC from this sorry state of affairs. Thanks in advance.

My rig:

i3 processor 3200MHz

8 GB RAM at 1333MHz

GT 710 card

Using proprietary nvidia drivers

Currently runs Ubuntu and Windows 10

Intel DH61BF Motherboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to boot windows to see if it works correctly? This should mean that there are no physical problem with your graphic card, and so the problem is only related to Ubuntu and its configuration. A kind of same thing happened to me too twice. The advice i can give you is to proceed with the following steps, if one doesn't solve your problem, go to the next one (you should be able to execute commands via tty, usually ctrl+alt+f1 or f2,f3...f6, it will asks for login, give the username of your account and then the password when you'll be asked to):

- `dconf reset -f /org/compiz` an reboot
- `sudo service lightdm restart` (assuming you're using unity)
- `sudo service lightdm stop` and then `sudo service lightdm start` if it doesn't reboot itself in a few seconds also give the `reboot` command
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
- try to uninstall and reinstall your desktop environment, search for instructions to do this or go to the next step
- try adding another desktop environment, such as gnome, `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` then reboot
- uninstall and reinstall drivers for your graphic card, so search for the supported drivers by ubuntu 16.04 for your graphic card model and install them
- switch to another graphic card, of you have it. `prime-select` and then with tab it should suggest you possible options, select one different from nvidia, for instance for me worked `sudo prime-select intel`, obviously substitue "intel" with the one suggested by tab